# get Element by class resetting when selected by button

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that getelementbyclass is resetting when the add to cart button is clicked its only storing one at a time i want it to store multiple i had similar problem with grand total but fixed it but i cannot use the same logic to it since it will get me nan any help ?

```js
   

 var addtocartbuttons = document.getElementsByClassName(`cart`)
    for (let i = 0; i < addtocartbuttons.length; i++) {
      var button = addtocartbuttons[i]
      button.addEventListener(`click`, lang1)
    }

    function lang1(event) {
      var target = event.srcElement;
      var button = event.target
      var shopitem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
      var title = shopitem.getElementsByClassName(`title`)[0].innerText;
      console.log(title)
      res2 = document.getElementsByClassName(`result2`)
      res2.textContent = title
      console.log(res2)
    }
```

```html
  

  <div class="product-categorie-box">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="grid-view">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <div class="products-single fix">
              <div class="box-img-hover">
                
                <img src="../../petuta/pizza/margerita.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
                <div class="mask-icon">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Compare"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <a class="cart" href="#">Add to Cart</a> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="why-text">
                <h4 class="title" id="title1"> Kids</h4>
                <h5 class = "price"> €6.00</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

but when button is pressed the text content in res2 despairs and put the new data any ideas?

Here is the console.log:

```
(HTMLCollection [div.result2, textContent: "Olives"]
0: div.result2
length: 1
textContent: "Olives")
```

The array only stays of the length of 1 I want it to keep storing how can I do that?  I want to store the text content in res2 even when the button is clicked.
I'm making a website which sends email with an order, and when I send email only the first one get sends and even in the console it appears the length of 1 then gets reset  when add to cart button is clicked.
ps.
i have 33 of these product-categorie-box so I would need some fix
I didnt use get element by id i used get element by class yet i still get one only can

ps i tried

```
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  var elems =  elems[i];
element2= elems.getElementsByClassName(`result2`)[0]
    console.log(element2)
}
```

but still same problem

Comment: Which `getElementByClassName` are you talking about? ```document.getElementsByClassName(`cart`)``` or ```document.getElementsByClassName(`result2`)```?

Comment: You need to index it: `res2 = document.getElementsByClassName(`result2`)[0]`

Comment: Where is `class="result2"` in your HTML?

Comment: You can't add to a NodeList. If you want to create more DIVs, you need to use `document.createElement` and then use `appendChild` to add them to the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar i think you found me a fix ty just need to check i reply if it works

Answer (score 0):

I manged to get a fix with the help of barmar

```
function lang1(event) {
        var target =  event.srcElement;
        var button =event.target
    var shopitem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopitem.getElementsByClassName(`title`)[0].innerText;
    var node =document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
var textnode =(`${title}`)
node.innerHTML=textnode
    // Create a text node                              // Append the text to <li>
var cnode=document.getElementsByClassName("result2")[0]
cnode.prepend(node)
console.log(cnode.textContent)
```